# Why RxJS operators is faster than Javascript array method to filter and map array with large size?

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs

```
import { of, from, asyncScheduler } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

let arr = [];
console.log("A");
console.log(new Date());
for(let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
  arr.push(i);
}

console.log("B");
console.log(new Date());

let arr2 = arr.filter(x => x%2 === 0)
  .map(x => x * 3)
  .map(x => x * 3)
  .map(x => x * 3);

console.log("C");
console.log(new Date());
console.log(arr2.length);

const source = from(arr).pipe(
  filter(x => x%2 === 0),
  map(x => x * 3),
  map(x => x * 3),
  map(x => x * 3)
);

console.log("D");
console.log(new Date());

let arr3 = [];

source.subscribe(x => arr3.push(x),
x => {},
() => { console.log("E");console.log(new Date()); }
);

console.log("F");
console.log(new Date());
console.log(arr3.length);
```

This is my code for test.

I test array filter and map performance between RxJS operators and methods of Javascript array.

For 10,000,000 size array, I did 1 filter and 3 maps.

JS methods takes about 3 seconds (time gap between console log B and C),

but RxJS takes less then 1 second (time gap between console log D and E)

As I check for 100 size array, JS is clearly faster, but for large size array RxJS is faster.

I wonder how RxJS can be faster than native JS implement. Please help me.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-7qflvl?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: I imagine it's because RxJS is using lazy evaluation on the entire chain of operations, whereas plain JS will do one complete traversal for `.filter` then another three complete traversal for the `.map` calls.

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't have the same behavior, so that might be the reason why it appears like RxJS is faster.

In particular in this code:

```
let arr2 = arr.filter(x => x%2 === 0)
  .map(x => x * 3)
  .map(x => x * 3)
  .map(x => x * 3);
```

With each `filter()` and `map()` you're creating a new array of 10M or 5M items. So in this case you create 10M items, then process it with `.filter(x => x%2 === 0)` that returns a new array of 5M items and so on.

However, RxJS `from()` will iterate the array only once and never create any new arrays. It will take each item and run it through one `filter()` and three `map()` operators which is therefore much more efficient.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what is totally difference between them. 

Answer (score 1):

The test results in my PC are different from yours.
I think it may vary depending on PC environment.

- Chrome v78.0.3904.97 64bit

  - C-B: 521 ms
  - E-D: 818 ms
- Firefox v70.0 64bit

  - C-B: 369 ms
  - E-D: 493 ms

Below is my PC environment.

- CPU: Intel i7-8700
- OS: windows 10 64bit

Comment: I tested on other PC. It seems like that you're right